# node removal during AST rewriting

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Assume that I have a tree node like `^(Root child1 child2)` and the root node of `child1` may have several children. The problem is that when I rewrite the above tree using the following rule, all the children of `child1` will be replaced by `child2`, but I want them to be preserved and `child2`'s tree be appended to `child1`'s children list. How should I do this?

```
^(Root ch1=child1 ch2=child2)
  -> ^($ch1 $ch2)
```

Answer (score 0):

By placing `$ch1` as the first element after the `^(` operator, you've told ANTLR that you want that element treated like a *node* instead of like a *tree*. This usage always automatically discards all children if any exist. To get the functionality you are after, you will have to break up the `child1` based on its root node and child trees.

```
^(Root ^(Child1Root (ch1c+=.)*) child2)
  -> ^(Child1Root $ch1c* child2)
```